# Building Profile Preference Category

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, preferenceactivity

I want to create settings where I have preferences that I can change user's profile which includes names and profile photo. The closest example is how WhatsApp changes the profile (see link below).

I have a working Preferences Activity, and also have a working custom Activity that currently changes user profile details. To make user experience a bliss, I want them all combined, under PreferenceScreen.

Searching all documentation, google and SO, I could not find anything to help me customize the preference category. Any help or even pointer is appreciated

[image: Text]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading and searching, it seems impossible for now without writing your own way. So I decided to write my own custom preference activity